# Generate unique hash for amazon purchase order report

Tags: php

My problem is that I can't figure a method for generating a unique hash for amazon purchase order reports so I can import them without duplicates in my MySQL table.

The way I'm doing it right now is:

1. I load the CSV file (example => https://gofile.io/?c=A8McUw) into a associative array
2. I generate a unique key using md5 like so:

`$hash = md5($row['order_id'] . $row['asin'] . $row['product_category'] . $row['seller_name'] . $row['order_quantity'] . $row['item_quantity'])`

3. I check if the $hash key exists and if yes I update the entry, if not it will insert a new one

This has worked for a few times but now I keep getting duplicate entries and I'm guessing it's because the order of the rows keeps changing every time new orders are added. I looked over the report and those columns are the only ones that are constant and can be used to uniquely identify the row.

Comment: Use the timestamp with microseconds and hash it with Sha. Md5 is not good enough, there can be duplicates

Comment: There are several things to keep in mind when generating unique identifiers.  Can you edit your question with the answers to the six questions I give in "[Unique Random Identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers)"?

Comment: "unique hash" is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution that works using the item order in which they come in from the amazon generated CSV. The only downside to this is if Amazon suddenly decides to change the order.

```
class Foo
{
    private $itemIndex = [];

    private function generateUniqueIdentifierForRow(array $row, $i = 1)
    {
        $str = $row['order_id'] . $row['asin'] . $i;

        return hash('sha256', $str);
    }

    public function uniqueRows($rows)
    {
        $uniqueRows = [];

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $hash = $this->generateUniqueIdentifierForRow($row);

            if (isset($this->hashDuplicatesIndexes[$hash]) || array_key_exists($hash, $this->itemIndex)) {
                $this->itemIndex[$hash]++;
                $hash = $this->generateUniqueIdentifierForRow($row, $this->itemIndex[$hash]);
            } else {
                $this->itemIndex[$hash] = 1;
            }

            $row['hash'] = $hash;
            $uniqueRows[] = $row;
        }

        return $uniqueRows;
    }
}
```